# How I select a cell in editing mode of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In not edit mode(setEditing:NO), selecting cell is possible.
But in edit mode(red minus icon appears), I can't select cells and didSelect method isn't invoked.
How I resolve this? Help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use commitEditingStyle instead and check indexpath